# Static Class in Abstract Class

Tags: java, static, abstract

```
abstract class MyClass{

    static class StaticClass{
        public void showAdd(){
            System.out.println(" show add");
        }
    }
}

public class SampleClass extends MyClass{

    public static void main(String[] args){
         MyClass myClass = new SampleClass();
         MyClass.StaticClass staticClass = new MyClass.StaticClass();
         staticClass.showAdd();
    }
}
```

Output is proper as expected but how can we write **new** with an **abstract** class??

Comment: Thanks for editing. I usually gets confused while posting the question here. Thanks again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not doing `new` on the abstract class but on the inner class that exists in this abstract class. In this case the abstract class is acting as a namespace.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot instantiate an abstract class. Your example "works" because you are not really instantiating an abstract class.

```
MyClass myClass = new SampleClass();
```

SampleClass is a child and an implementation of the MyClass class, and because of that it is not abstract. So that line simply works as it should. Try replace `new SampleClass()` to `new MyClass()` and you will get an compiler error.

```
MyClass.StaticClass staticClass = new MyClass.StaticClass();
```

which is the same in this case as:

```
StaticClass staticClass = new StaticClass();
```

Is just an instantiation of a Inner Class declared inside an abstract class. Since this inner class is not abstract it may be instantiated.

Answer (score 0):

You can't create instance for abstract class (unless you use reflections). So, if you do `new MyClass()`, then only it is compile time error. Otherwise it works fine, which is the case with your example.

You are not creating instance for static class using  `new MyClass.StaticClass();`

Abstract class is the class which is not full implemented (some facts are left for subclasses) . Read this [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html) and [how inner classes work](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html).

Static inner classes are like static variables of class.

Comment: It is working properly because you are not creating instance for MyClass(), but static inner classes are different.

Comment: hey, I know about abstract classes in java. But I just keep one doing things with code and gets confused. Thats it only. BTW, thanks for your quick reply :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

**1.** Outer class is very possessive of its inner class (whether static or non-static).

**2.** So to access the inner class (static or non-static) Outer class is needed.

**eg:**

```
Outer.Inner i = new Outer.Inner();
```

In the above example i am **NOT Initiating the outer class, moreover in your case its abstract, so there
is no question of it being initialized**,but its the **Inner Static Class, also known as Top-level class is initialized.**

Comment: Yeah, Thats what vainolo said below. Thanks for reply.

Comment: Jaikrat singh please read my comment to JahN EstaCado, there is a piece of information abt non-static inner class, i hope that will be helpful for later use...thanks

Answer (score -1):

An abstract class can not be instantiated! That's the Java rules.

Comment: Please justify the downvote in order to learn from my "mistakes"

Comment: Well i DID NOT down voted you, but as the guy who downvoted your answer, is not bothered to answer your query.... Well let me answer it then.... When we initiate the `Outer.Inner i = new Outer.Inner();` we are initiating the Inner static class, not the Abstract Outerclass, if this was a non-static inner class, then it would have been a problem cause in that case we need an outer class instance like this.. `Outer o = new Outer();` then  `Outer.Inner i = o.new Inner();`

Comment: If this were a non-static inner class even then there would not be any problem. Because in that case we would write something like,

MyClass myClass = new SampleClass();
MyClass.StaticClass obj = myClass.new StaticClass();

**Consider my above example as a base for this code snippet**